# fabricjs TypeError: this.canvas is undefined

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have defined `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas')` but during creating a function I am getting this error: `TypeError: this.canvas is undefined`. Here are my codes:

```
 if (mood === 'hline') {
   canvas.freeDrawingBrush = vLinePatternBrush;
   }

       var vLinePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);

        vLinePatternBrush.getPatternSrc = function() {

          var patternCanvas = canvas;
          patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = 10;
          var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');

          ctx.strokeStyle = $("#drawing-color").val();
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0, 5);
          ctx.lineTo(10, 5);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.stroke();

          return patternCanvas;
        };
```

In where I did mistake?

Comment: Why are using context directly as if you were using a pure canvas (and not a FabricJS one)? Are you sure the error is thrown from the piece of code you submitted?

Comment: Here is more detail about the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689070/fabricjs-freedrawing-hline-brush